# Free shipping option not going away

Tags: magento-1, shipping, coupon, free-shipping

I have a Shipping Method for Free Shipping if price is >= $100. "show method if not applicable" is set to no..

I have a shopping cart price rule coupon. 10% discount. Free Shipping is set to No.

When a customer makes a purchase over $100, enters the discount code, and begins the checkout...the option for Free Shipping is still there!

I think it doesn't let the transaction actually happen, but showing it as an option is confusing customers, and causing transactions to be "cancelled".

Comment: Sorry. I wasn't clear. I want the shipping option to disappear if they are using a coupon. I thought I turned off Free shipping for that scenario when I set the coupon attribute to be "Free shipping = No". BUT it's still showing it as an option in the checkout.

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying this happens when the discount drops the price below $100? That would be abnormal.

The 'Free Shipping' option in Shopping Cart Price Rules does not work in reverse as far as I know. What I mean is, it will not override the admin configuration to allow free shipping by setting it to NO for that coupon. So if the order is still over $100 after the coupon is applied it will still allow the free shipping method.

Answer (score 0):

Magento calculates free shipping based on subtotal, not grand total.

But you can do something like this:

app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Model/Carrier/Freeshipping.php

change line 60:

```
|| ($request->getBaseSubtotalInclTax() >=   $this->getConfigData('free_shipping_subtotal'))
```

to

```
|| ($request->getPackageValueWithDiscount() >= $this->getConfigData('free_shipping_subtotal')
```